# How do i edit a post

Tags: bug, status-norepro, editing

I have not been here for a while, so i am unsure if it is just something that is happening in the past couple of hours or what. But i am unable to edit the post. I get "Page not found" when i click on 'Edit' links.

I have tried several approaches already, opening in a new tab, actually pasting the edit link into the address bar (thinking that it maybe some sort of AJAX shenanigans. But none of this has helped.

---

I have found what the actual issue was seconds after posting... it always happens like this for me, i wait for hours trying everything, then then find the solution as soon as i ask for help.

The actual issue was that i have reset my User Agent string to a different value doing something else, and apparently, for whatever reason, StackExchange completely breaks if you are not on a "good" browser. Silly!

Answer (score 5):

This is by-designed. Stack Exchange prevents editing for some values of the user agent to prevent bots.

As [explained by Oded](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/288094/241919) (former SE employee),

> One heuristic our system uses to identify bots is single word user agents - and we do not allow bots to edit pages.
>
> This is a simple and effective heuristic, and unless one changes their user agent in the manner you described, wouldn't cause problem to people.

Comment: This is basically what is called "security by obscurity". At the very least it could show "User agent disallowed" error or something similar.

Comment: @v010dya - I agree with your point that a useful error would be nice, but this isn't security through obscurity, it's more akin to spam filtering. You can't outright stop spam/bots, the best you can do is try and find patterns to reduce the worst whilst minimising false positives.

Comment: @Alconja Good analogy with spam. Imagine if somebody comes up with an idea to stop spam, which would require everybody to use only a set of mail clients to send. All other clients will be given an error that has nothing to do with what is actually happening. Would this be a "good" anti-spam measure? I think that we can agree, that it is a rubbish measure, and this proposal should be laughed at.